# Correct C syntax for "address of" character pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to pass into a function the address of a character pointer array, what would be the correct function declaration/prototype syntax for that?

I tried:

```
    void myFunc(char &*a[]);
```

But get an expected ; , or ) before & error.

I also tried:

```
    void myFunc(char **a);
```

Since the pointer I would be passing in is indeed a pointer to a pointer, but I get yet another error. This time the error has to do with: expected `char **`, but got `char *[]`

Or something like that. I have since attempted other solutions so I not remember exactly the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the error message and the bit of code that produced the error message.

Comment: Can you provide some more code, especially how you are attempting to call `myFunc` as it is stated now the question is not clear.

Comment: Based on what you've said, the second approach sounds like it should be correct.  Try it again, and this time post the actual error message (not from memory this time) along with the line it's complaining about.  You also might want to show the the code that's calling the function so we can verify that you're doing what you're describing.

Comment: Please provide the code that how you are calling myfunc() it would be easy for us to debug

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have an array declared as

```
char *a[N];
```

and you want to pass a pointer to the array, as in

```
foo( &a );
```

then the prototype for `foo` needs to be

```
void foo( char *(*aptr)[N] );
```

Note that in this case, the size of the array *must* be declared; a pointer to an N-element array is a different type from a pointer to an M-element array.

Normally, you don't want to do this; instead, you would normally just pass the array expression like so:

```
foo ( a );
```

and the corresponding prototype would be:

```
void foo ( char **aptr );
```

Except when it is the operand of the`sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to`T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: What I was intending on doing was passing a pointer to the array of pointers and assigning each pointer in the original array to some block of memory with a string stored there.

Comment: Must the size of the array be declared in the function definition? Or can an array with defined length be passed in?

Comment: It is not necessarily to declare the size of the array; C will accept `void foo(char *(*aptr)[]);`. The type of `aptr` is then incomplete, but the C implementation does not need it as long as no expression requiring the size of `*aptr` is evaluated. The called function will need to know which elements in the array it should operate on (e.g., the first `J` elements).

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated Answer For Modified Problem Statement

Given what you have said in comments, there is no need to pass a pointer to an array. You can simply pass a pointer to the first element of the array. Such a pointer suffices because the remaining elements of the array are obviously located after the first element.

To write a function that sets pointers in an array of pointers to `char`, do this:

```
void MyFunction(int NumberToSet, char *Pointers[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberToSet; ++i)
    {
        Pointers[i] = SomeString;
    }
}
```

In the above, `SomeString` must have type “pointer to `char`”. This could be a string, such as `"Hello"`, or an array of `char` (which is automatically converted to a pointer to `char`), or some identifier `x` that has been declared as `char *x` (and has been initialized or assigned), for example.

To use this function, call it like this:

```
char *MyArrayOfPointers[SomeNumber];
MyFunction(NumberOfPointersIWantToSet, MyArrayOfPointers);
```

---

#### Original Answer

In most cases, to pass an array of pointers to `char` to a function, it suffices to pass the address of the first element. In this case, you would use either of these (they are equivalent):

```
void myFunc(char **a)
void myFunc(char *a[])
```

If you truly want to pass the address of the array, you would use:

```
void myFunc(char *(*a)[])
```

In this case, the type of `a` is incomplete, since the dimension is missing. Depending on what you intend to do with `a`, you may need to provide the dimension in the declaration.

When calling `myFunc` and passing it some array declared as `char *array[N];`, you would pass it, in the former case, as `myFunc(array)` and, in the latter case, as `myFunc(&array)`.

Comment: I intended to pass a pointer to the array of pointers. Using such a pointer I was going to assign each pointer in the array to a block of memory containing a string.

Comment: I understand that `char **a` is a pointer to a char pointer. Is `char *a[]` a char pointer to an array? If so, it seems to follow naturally that `char *(*a)[]` is a pointer to a pointer to an array.

Comment: If you pass into a function `myFunc(array)`, that would be a pointer to the first index of the array, or the pointer that IS at the first index of the array?

Comment: @sherrellbc: No, `char *a[]` is not a pointer to an array. It is, in a normal declaration, an array of pointers to `char`. In a function parameter declaration, it is adjusted to be `char **`.

Comment: @sherrellbc: In `myFunc(array)`, `array` is converted to a pointer ot the first element. It is not converted to the first element; the value passed is not the pointer that is in the first element of the array.

Comment: `char *(*a)[]` is not a correct type. An array type needs a length.

Comment: @newacct: It does not need a length. `char *[]` is indeed an incomplete type, but the C standard permits declaring a pointer to an incomplete type, so `char *(*a)[]` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

try this as a function definition `void myFunc(char *a[])` or `void myFunc(char **a)` then  use it this way :

```
char *arr[20];
myFunc(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaration

```
void myFunc(char &*a[]);
```

is not a valid C syntax.
To pass the *address of character pointer arrays*, use this instead

```
void myFunc(char *(*a)[]);
```

`*(*a)[]` in the above function declares **`a` as pointer to array of pointers to `char`s**. Must note that `a` has an incompatible type. A suffix is needed in `[]` to make it complete.

Comment: void myFunc(char &*a[]); is it possible in c++, I ran into a similar issue before when I was trying to do that

Comment: @aboody; In C++ it is possible to call by reference but not in C.

Comment: After downvoting please leave a comment. It should be appreciated.

Comment: that wasnt me, however take at the error message I got here http://ideone.com/FkK2ed

Comment: @aboody; In C++ `void myFunc(char &a[]);` could be a valid syntax but not in C. `void myFunc(char &*a[]);` is not valid in either.

Comment: ok thanks, that what I thought, however, I was trying to pass it that way before

Comment: `char *(*a[])` is the same as `char **a[]`; the `[]` bind to `a`, then `*`, then `*`. To have a pointer to an array, you must bind the `*` to `a` first, using `(*a)` (“a pointer to”), then have the brackets (“an array”), then an `*` and a `char` (of pointer to `char`), yielding `char *(*a)[]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; I think `char *(*a)[]` is a *pointer to a pointer to array of `char`s*

Comment: In the grammar of the C standard, `*(*a)[]` is a declarator which is parsed as a pointer `*` and a direct-declarator `(*a)[]`. The latter is parsed as a direct-declarator `(*a)` and `[]`. Therefore `*` binds to `a` first (so `a` is a pointer), then it binds to `[]` (so it is a pointer to an array), then it binds to the outer `*` (so it is a pointer to an array of pointers). You can also check [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*%28*a%29%5B%5D).

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Interesting! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you are almost on the right path. `void myFunc(char *a[]);`

Example

```
void fun(char *a[]){
    printf("%s",*a);    //for accessing the next element do a+1
    }

int main(void) {
    char *x[3];
    x[0]="abcd";
    fun(x);   // here you are passing the address first array element 
    return 0;
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/0GJH3A)**

Answer (score -1):

First of all, C is in general a "pass by reference" language.  Some data items such as integers, floats, and single characters can be passed by value.  But, arrays of those same data types are **ALWAYS** passed by reference.

Thus, when you say "I need to pass into a function the address of a character pointer array" then simply declare an array of character pointers in your function prototype as:

```
void myFunc(char *a[]);
```

Thus, `char *` declares a char pointer and `a[]` defines an array of them.  To check this declaration refer to: http://www.cdecl.org/ which parses this expression as a "declare a as array of pointer to char".

The technical point is that the `*` binds with `char` rather than with `a[]`.

So, C will pass a pointer to the data structure that you have declared.  A discussion on this topic could delve into double pointers but for this question such a discussion is probably off topic.

Comment: Your first paragraph is completely wrong. C is a pass by value and doesn't have references. Pointers are passed by value.

Comment: self, but the pointer refers to data that is to be modified for the caller.  It is NOT possible to modify the value of the passed ptr, hence it is passed by value, a value that references what is of actual interest.

Comment: Then clarify what you meant when you used word reference. Currently it is wrong.

Comment: self, I think that the statement "C is in general a "pass by reference" language" is sufficient.